# TypeScript compilation fails due to invalid type (although the type is correct)

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm struggling with one issue, and I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {

  console.log(user.id)
  
})
```

Here, the `reaction` argument has a type of `MessageReaction | PartialMessageReaction` and `user` argument has a type of `User | PartialUser`. Property `id` does exist on type `User` and therefore there should be nothing wrong with this code. But when I compile it using nodemon:

```
index.ts:38:20 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'MessageReaction | PartialMessageReaction'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'MessageReaction'.

38   console.log(user.id)
```

as you can see, for some reason the compiler thinks that `user` is of type `MessageReaction`. I tried logging out the `user` argument and this is the output:

```
User {
  id: '888509500842184701',
  bot: false,
  system: false,
  flags: UserFlagsBitField { bitfield: 0 },
  username: "[hidden]",
  discriminator: "[hidden]",
  avatar: 'a5b93bc5ac8fc7fb3e02d85af65b8ba7',
  banner: undefined,
  accentColor: undefined
}
```

Is this a problem with compiler? What can I do to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Full code:

```
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js'

const client = new Client({intents: [GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions]})

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("client ready!");
  
})

client.on("messageCreate", async (m) => {
  if(m.channelId !== "1038172955621994496") return
  if(m.author.id == client.user!.id) return

  if(m.content === ";setup" && m.member?.permissions.has("Administrator")){

    await m.delete()
    
    const msg = await m.channel.send({embeds: [    {
      "title": "Create a Ticket",
      "description": "React with :question: to create a ticket",
      "color": 30719
    }]})
  
    await msg.react('❓')

    msg.createReactionCollector()

  }
})

client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {

  console.log(user.id)

})

client.login("***").then(() => {
  console.log("bot running")
})
```

Comment: `id` must exist on both `User` and `PartialUser` for this to compile.

Comment: Visual Studio Code doesn't highlight any errors, it's completely fine code wise. It's an issue with the compiler.

Comment: also, the error message tells us that the type of `user` is `MessageReaction | PartialMessageReaction` unlike what you said in your question.

Comment: `ts-node` infers the type incorrectly. When I console.log `console.log(reaction.constructor.name, user.constructor.name)` I see this output: `MessageReaction User`

Comment: Where is that type coming from? Have you defined `client.on` ?

Comment: `client.on` is defined internally, since the `Client` class extends `EventEmitter` from node.js.

Comment: This is likely an issue with `ts-node`. If you try compiling with regular `typescript`, does it work?

Comment: I updated the question with full code. For some reason `tsc index.ts` compilation throws 721 errors (all from `discord.js` index.d.ts file)

Comment: You should update your `tsc` version. I just had the same issue.

Comment: Looks like `user` is not of `User` type but rather `MessageReaction | PartialMessageReaction`

Comment: @Antoniossss the compiler is wrong. `user` should in fact be a `User` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by `npm i typescript`. Not sure how it fixed my issue, but it did the job.

Comment: probably a bug fix on the typescript package, could be interesting to know the old version you had.